# php: I don't understand the output of substring

Tags: php, substring

I am parsing a file to put its content into a database.

I test every line, if its content should ignored or handled,
using substring on the first four characters.

My snippet is ..

```
$inputLine = 'Baseline 100%T,,...,,208a,,208b,,Leerfilter,';

$check = substr($inputLine, 0, 4);

var_dump($check)
```

My output from var_dump is:

```
string(4) "﻿B"
```

Which is not what I expected. I expected "Base" as output but it tells me having a string containing four characters and its content is just "B".

The input is from a normal text file, like hundreds before of fine working files of the same kind and format which has been successfully parsed before.

Has anyone an idea what it means

> string(4) "B"

Thanks in forward.

Comment: are there non-printing characters contained in the string? maybe your encoding is utf-32? you should read about multibyte-strings in php

Comment: Time to learn about NON-printable characters.

Comment: [It should print `Base`](https://3v4l.org/JIvD9), so I'm going to guess you have some invisible characters at the beginning of the string.

Comment: When I copy & paste that code if gives "string(4) Base" as expected. Check your encoding. Elsewise do a `$check = mb_substr($inputLine, 0, 4);`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I opened the file in a hex editor and found three non printed dots leading my string. After removing this, everything worked fine.